# PHP 5.6 not working with virtualhosts on Redhat 7.2

Tags: php, apache, redhat

I am running Apache 2.4 on Redhat 7.2, I have also installed PHP 5.6.

I created a vhosts file for a site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ex1.mysite.com
ServerName ex1.mysite.com
ErrorLog logs/ex1.mysite.com-error-log
CustomLog logs/ex1.mysite.com-access_log common
<Directory /var/www/html/ex1.mysite.com>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

I am able to view index.html in my browser, however when I attempt to load a PHP file, I get a message "File Not Found". I am able to view a PHP file in the default location (var/www/html).

Is there a way to get PHP working in a virtual host?

Comment: Shouldn't 'default location' be `/var/www/html/ex1.mysite.com` as in config and not `/var/www/html`?

Comment: try appending a `/` slash at the end of the path in this line `<Directory /var/www/html/ex1.mysite.com>`,that is if @DenisAlexandrov's solution as suggestion above does not work.